# NVD3 linechart tooltips not following the mouse

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the NVD3 library to generate a linechart, and gave some data:

[image: screen shot 2014-10-31 at 13 39 44]

[image: screen shot 2014-10-31 at 13 40 25]

## The problem is, the interactive guideline shows up like this (specifically note the tooltips):

[image: screen shot 2014-10-31 at 13 35 10]

[image: screen shot 2014-10-31 at 13 35 19]
Note that I only get a tooltip at the start and end of the linechart.

## Now, I set `useInteractiveGuideline(false)`

[image: screen shot 2014-10-31 at 13 34 59]

This DOES show up correctly, but is very laggy and I'd like to use `useInteractiveGuideline(true)`.

Is suspect this is a bug in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need to define the

```
.x(function (d) {
    return xValues.indexOf(d.x);
 })
```

the code listed below works fine in our project:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
                    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                            .margin({bottom: 20})
                            .x(function (d) {
                                return xValues.indexOf(d.x);
                            })
                            .useInteractiveGuideline(false)
                                .forceY([-10, 40])
                            .tooltipContent(function (key, x, y, e) {
                                return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
                                    '<p>' + e.point.y + ' at ' + x + '</p>';
                            })
                        ;

                    chart.xAxis
                        //.axisLabel($translate.instant('loadTests.overview.testRuns.grid.startOn'))
                        .showMaxMin(true)
                        .tickFormat(function (d) {
                            if (typeof(d) === 'number' && d >= 0 && d < xValues.length) {
                                return d3.time.format('%m/%d')(new Date(1 * xValues[d]));
                            }
                            return 0;
                        })
                        .tickValues(xValues)
                    ;
...
```

hope it helps!
it would be better if you could create a fiddle for this.

Comment: This helped me out. Thank you!