# Chart Interactive Guideline defaults to farthest value of opposite side of cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, nvd3.js

I'm new to UI and using nvd3 with Bootstrap, and a line graph is now doing something peculiar: when the mouse is hovered over either half of the chart, the Interactive Guideline and highlighted (x,y) point reverts to the farthest value on the other half of the graph.  In other words, when hovering over the right half of the chart, the first data point is selected, and when hovering over the left half of the chart, the last data point is selected.  I've verified that the graph data is accurate.  I'm trying to make a fiddle and will update this post if the fiddle works, but the Javascript for the graph appears correct.  Thanks very much in advance!

Here is the Scripts section of the View:

```
@section Scripts{
    <!-- page specific plugins -->
    <!-- nvd3 charts -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/novus-nvd3/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- flot charts-->
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
    <!-- clndr -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/underscore-js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/CLNDR/src/clndr.js"></script>
    <!-- easy pie chart -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- owl carousel -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- dashboard functions -->
    <script src="/Content/js/apps/tisa_dashboard.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cumulativeTestData() {
            var closes = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Coordinates))')
            return [
                {
                    key: "Prices",
                    values: closes //These generate in source
                },
            ];
        }
    </script>
}
```

Here is the Javascript chart code:

```
$(function () {
    // nvd3 charts
    tisa_nvd3_charts.cumulativeLine();
    // flot charts
    tisa_flot_charts.social();
    tisa_flot_charts.browsers();
    // mini calendar
    tisa_calendar.miniCal();
    // easy chart pie
    tisa_easy_pie_chart.init();
    // latest images carousel
    tisa_carousel.latest_images();
})

// nvd3 charts
tisa_nvd3_charts = {
    cumulativeLine: function () {
        if ($('#nvd3_cumulativeLine').length) {
            nv.addGraph(function () {
                var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                          .margin({ left: 100 })  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
                          .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
                          .x(function (d) { return d[0] })
                          .y(function (d) { return d[1] })
                          .color(d3.scale.category20().range())
                          .transitionDuration(250)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
                          .clipVoronoi(false);

                chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
                    //.axisLabel('Time (ms)')
                    .tickFormat(function (d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
                    });


                chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
                    //.axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
                    .tickFormat(d3.format('$,.3f'));

                /* Done setting the chart up? Time to render it!*/
                //var myData = sinAndCos();   //You need data...

                d3.select('#nvd3_cumulativeLine svg')    //Select the <svg> element you want to render the chart in.   
                    .datum(cumulativeTestData())         //Populate the <svg> element with chart data...
                    .call(chart);                        //Finally, render the chart!

                //Update the chart when window resizes.
                nv.utils.windowResize(function () { chart.update() });
                return chart;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the references in the HTML header:

```
<!-- nvd3 charts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lib/novus-nvd3/nv.d3.min.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="/Content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- easing -->
<script src="/Content/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap js plugins -->
<script src="/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- top dropdown navigation -->
<script src="/Content/js/tinynav.js"></script>
<!-- perfect scrollbar -->
<script src="/Content/lib/perfect-scrollbar/min/perfect-scrollbar-0.4.8.with-mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<!-- common functions -->
<script src="/Content/js/tisa_common.js"></script>

<!-- page specific stylesheets -->

<!-- owl carousel -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lib/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<!-- google webfonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400&amp;subset=latin-ext,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css">
<!-- date range picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lib/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css">
<!-- timepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lib/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
<!-- ion.rangeSlider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lib/ion.rangeSlider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css">
<!-- bootstrap switches -->
<link href="/Content/lib/bootstrap-switch/build/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- 2col multiselect -->
<link href="/Content/lib/multi-select/css/multi-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- multiselect, tagging -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/lib/select2/select2.css">

<!-- main stylesheet -->
<link href="/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<!-- moment.js (date library) -->
<script src="/Content/lib/moment-js/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but the interactive guideline works if the .useInteractiveGuideline(true) line is commented out.  I imagine changing it to false would also work, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676380/nvd3-linechart-tooltips-not-following-the-mouse) person originally did.  I had defined the x-axis values, though, so that link still didn't work for me.  The only thing that did was commenting out the Interactive Guideline.